Solarium Solr SSL Issue
I am using Pantheon's hosting environment for WordPress websites. I am building a custom plugin that integrates Solr into the WordPress search. I am using docker and was able to spin up a Solr server locally

However, on Pantheon's environment I am receiving this error:

Here is my Pantheon configuration for Solr:
$options = [
        'endpoint' => [
            'localhost' => [
                'host' => getenv('PANTHEON_INDEX_HOST'),
                'port' => getenv('PANTHEON_INDEX_PORT'),
                'scheme' => get_default_scheme(),
                'path' => compute_path(),
                'ssl' => [
                    'local_cert' => get_cert_path(),
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];

and my local dev config:
$options = [
        'endpoint' => [
            'localhost' => [
                'host' => 'solr',
                'port' => 8983,
                'path' => '/solr/my_solr_core',
                'ssl' => [
                    'local_cert' => get_cert_path(),
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];

Maybe someone knows the issue, I've been debugging for over a week.
Thanks!
